# Coldfusion encrypt to perl crypt

Tags: perl, encryption, coldfusion, crypt

Is it possible to duplicate output from the perl crypt function using ColdFusion decrypt?
I am not familiar with encryption programming, but as I understand it crypt uses the DES algorithm unless otherwise indicated. Coldfusion can use the DES algorithm, but I don't know what other parameters to use.

Allow me to clarify my situation. I am working with a vendor supplied application written in perl. My local toolset is mainly ColdFusion. I would like to enhance the vendor supplied login function with a 'lost your password/reset password' function. I would prefer not to change the vendor source code, which I have access to, since it get upgraded regularly and I don't want to have to keep applying the changes. The best solution, for a host of reasons, is to emulate the perl crypt() function output in ColdFusion so I can build the password reset function externally to the vendor application. It is admittedly an awkward and confusing situation.

I do not know if the emulation approach is feasible; if not it is back to the drawing board.

Comment: Link to an accurate description of what CF uses. - Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817407/tripledes-in-perl-php-coldfusion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196846/un-encrypting-re-encrypting-a-coldfusion-encrypted-string-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you didn't know, perl's crypt() function (and the crypt() function in the standard C library) is a one-way hashing function usually used for storing passwords. It's **not** an encryption function and there is no known decryption function.

As such, you're probably not looking for a function called decrypt(). I don't used Coldfusion, so I can't help you find the proper function.

Comment: IF that's the case look for at the HASH() Function in CF. You can specify the algorithm you need.