# generate TripleDES encrypted string, Base64 Encoded

Tags: php

i am using ccbill and making upgrade system . In that i need to pass the username or user id plus the key in TripleDES encrypted string, Base64 Encoded format . I know we can use `base64_encode` for base64 encoding . But how to achieve the requirements they want the value to be in ?

Comment: Don't they have some sort of demo for implementation that covers this? Check out their API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example from the mcrypt page in the PHP documentation has TripleDES for you
http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

```
<?php
    $key = "this is a secret key";
    $input = "Let us meet at 9 o'clock at the secret place.";

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    $base64encodedafter3des=base64_encode($encrypted_data);
?>
```

Also looks like someone has answered this question in perfect detail already.  Here is a link to his answer. 
You want the post by @Eric Kigathi about ccbill
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11925394/4179009

Comment: Thank you for your reply so i would need to encode this to base64 later or not ? and what is the secret key here ?

Comment: added the base64 encoding after it was encrypted

Comment: Greg can the key be empty ?

Comment: Greg you saved my life . LOL . Thank you so much for linking the post